# How to test if dynamic text content is in the document using React-testing-library and Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a simple note-taking application using jest and react-testing-library. The first test, I'm trying to do is testing if the route displays the correct entry.

However an issue I've encountered is that, any value dynamically added to the dom using react hooks is inaccessible by react-testing-library. However static text works fine.

entry.test.js

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { useState } from "react"
import { Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Entry from "./entry";

describe("Entry",() => {
    it("should retrieve a single entry",async() => {

        const entries = [{
            title:"test1",
            desc:"I went to the beach",
            id:444
        },{
            title:'test2',
            desc:"This is test 2",
            id:695
        }]

        const history = createMemoryHistory();
        history.push('/entry/444');
        render(
            <Router history={history}>
                 <Route exact path='/entry/:id'>
                    <Entry entries={entries} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        ,{route:'/entry/444'});
        
        screen.debug();
        const EntryTitle = screen.getByText('test1');
        await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('entry_title'));
         expect(screen.getByTestId('entry_title')).toHaveTextContent();
    })
})
```

entry.js

```
export default function Entry({entries,setEntry}) {
    const [isEditable,setEditable] = useState(false);
    const [entry,setCurrentEntry] = useState(null);
    const params = useParams();
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        getEntry();
    }, [])

    const getEntry = () => {
        const current = entries.filter(entry => entry.id === params.id);
        setCurrentEntry(current[0]);
        return current[0];    
    }
     return (
       <h4 data-testid='entry_title' className="subtitle entry_title">{entry && entry.title}</h4> 
    )
```

error message

```
  TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: test1. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

However using Screen.debug() returns:

```
  <h4 class="subtitle entry_title" data-testid="entry_title" />
```

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: The text isnt rendering to the screen with react-testing-library, so the queries don't work.

Comment: Please, provide the exact error, so it could be seen what's wrong. Currently it appears there's no test1, so it's a specific query that doesn't work, `screen.getByText('test1')`. You have to wait for it instead of entry_title because the latter is always expected to exist, `waitFor` doesn't serve a good purpose for it.

Comment: I tried  using waitfor on the actual text , but that didn't work either

Comment: Then debug what happens inside the component. I see the problem with id. It's supposed to be a string, while a number is given, isn't it?

Comment: @EstusFlask is correct. If I update the `getEntry` function in the component to `const current = entries.filter((entry) => String(entry.id) === params.id);`, then I do not get the "Unable to find an element..." error. I then get a failing test because `expect(screen.getByTestId("entry_title")).toHaveTextContent();` does not specify the expected text content.